# how to return a tuple from a dictionary that satisfy True value parameter in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

I have the following dictionary and I need to return the dictionary keys that only have a TRUE value as a tuple. For example, given my dictionary below the function should return ("madam", "1221").

revDict = {'hello world': False, 'madam': True, '1221': True}

I tried few way but non of them works:

#1

```
myTrueDict = (i for i in revDict if revDict.values() = True)
print(myTrueDict)
myTuple = tuple(myTrueDict.keys())
print(myTuple)
```

#2

```
myTrueDict = {k:v for (k,v) in revDict.items() if v = True}
print(myTrueDict)
myTuple = tuple(myTrueDict.keys())
print(myTuple)
```

Comment: `tuple(k for k, v in revDict.items() if v)`…?

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution works if you fix a typo with `if v = True` where it should be `if v == True`

```
revDict = {'hello world': False, 'madam': True, '1221': True}
myTrueDict = {k:v for (k,v) in revDict.items() if v == True}
myTuple = tuple(myTrueDict.keys())
print(myTuple)
```

However, you could simply get the keys ignoring the values as:

```
tuples = tuple(k for k, v in revDict.items() if v)
print(tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working proposal according to your #1 example:

```
revDict = {'hello world': False, 'madam': True, '1221': True}
myTrueDict = tuple(i for i in revDict if revDict[i] == True)
print(myTrueDict)
```

Output:

```
('madam', '1221')
```